# Is it possible to insert a row but only if a value does not already exist?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to insert a row, but only if one of the values already in the table does not exist?

I'm creating a *Tell A Friend* with referral points for an ecommerce system, where I need to insert the friend's email into the database table, but only if it doesn't already exist in the table. This is because I don't want any more than 1 person getting the referral points once the new customer signs up and purchases something. Therefore I want only one email ever once in the table.

I'm using PHP 4 and MySql 4.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the column is a primary key or a unique index:

```
INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES (email_address) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
email=email_address
```

Knowing my luck there's a better way of doing it though. AFAIK there's no equivalent of "ON DUPLICATE KEY DO NOTHING" in MySQL. I'm not sure about the email=email_Address bit, you could play about and see if it works without you having to specify an action. As someone states above though, if it has unique constraints on it nothing will happen anyway. And if you want all email addresses in a table to be unique there's no reason to specify it as unique in your column definition.

Comment: I set the email to a unique key in phpMyAdmin then used your code. And it worked great! Thank you

Comment: Re: no equivalent of ON DUPLICATE KEY DO NOTHING. See Todd's solution. Alternatively, you could probably do something like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=email, though it's certainly more wasteful.

Answer (score 33):

This works if you have a unique index or primary key on the column (EmailAddr in this example):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table (EmailAddr) VALUES ('test@test.com')
```

Using this if a record with that email already exists (duplicate key violation) instead of an error, the statement just fails and nothing is inserted.

See the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert.html) for more information.

Comment: "INSERT IGNORE" is the best answer, but REPLACE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is also an option if you want to reinsert the row for some reason (maybe a timestamp trigger or something).

Comment: Be wary of REPLACE incrementing your autoincrement - under the hood it's just a DELETE, INSERT.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Email=@Email) THEN INSERT INTO blah blah
```

That can be rolled into one database query.

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification/addition to naeblis's answer:

```
INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES (email_address)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

This way you don't have to throw `email=email_address` in there **and** you get the correct value for `LAST_INSERT_ID()` if the statement updates.

*Source:* MySQL Docs: 12.2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it, but what about a

```
try {
  mysql_query($sql);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}
```

combined with an unique field index in MySQL?

if it throws an exception then you know that you got a duplicated field.
Sorry if that don't answer your question..

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't think it solves my problem. I want a single query that either inserts the row, or does nothing if it fails.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, then the row won't be added. You can just log, or do nothing in the catch.

Comment: But with the previous query, it caused an error every time. I wanted it to fail silently within mySql.

Comment: This is a good approach to solving the problem outside of the DB, but it doesn't solve the problem in the DB which is, arguably, where this should be taken care of.

Comment: @Jeremiah Peschka - Wise words

Comment: AFAIK `mysql_query()` never throws exceptions when there is a SQL error, so I don't think this would have worked as is?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL offers [REPLACE INTO http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT,
>   except that if an old row in the table
>   has the same value as a new row for a
>   PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE  index, the
>   old row is deleted before the new row
>   is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If the email field was the primary key then the constraints on the table would stop a duplicate from being entered.