# How to insert data only if data doesn't already exist in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

This is what I'm doing right now:

> Execute a query and check if the date
>   to be inserted already exists in a
>   table.

If date doesn't exist:

> Another query will insert the date into the table.

How can these two query be combined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert a row but only if a value does not already exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285937/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-but-only-if-a-value-does-not-already-exist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert a row but only if a value does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285937/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-row-but-only-if-a-value-does-not-already-exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X WHERE A=B)
    INSERT INTO ...
```

Comment: I tried this: IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM abc WHERE date='2010-06-02' and position='5') INSERT INTO abc (date, position) VALUES ('2010-06-02','5') but it's throwing some error in MYSQL

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was for MySql. In that case, you may try this syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

If date is not a primary key, you may try adding a unique index on that (with that logic it's unique anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285980/20178):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table (EmailAddr) VALUES ('test@test.com')
```

Comment: nice solution, especially for the situation that nothing should be done if a record is already exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the two statements together into a stored procedure